# Facing issue While launching Logic App From VS Code

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I am facing below error while trying to launch logic app from VS code locally . I created logic app after installing extensions like -

1. Azure tools
2. Functions app tools extension v3.x
3. Logic App (Standard) extension
4. Azurite
5. ngFork for webhook

Below is the error I am getting when I click on overview from VS code  -

[image]

Also my workflow is basic and simple as below -

[image]

Any help would be appreciated ! thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

I have done repro from my end in my local environment, the below reasons are based on my analysis:

> Visual Studio 2022 doesn't include support for the Azure Logic Apps extension. You can refer this [MSDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-logic-apps-with-visual-studio#prerequisites) to check which version is supported for the logic apps extensions.

You can disable and reload the installed azure related extensions and then try launching a logic app in VS code.

And as you mentioned in the question, it may not be ngFork it is `ngrok` for webhooks extension which you need to install in your vs code. So currently ngrok is needed here as per my analysis and ngrok is mainly used to distribute proxy services to run in any cloud environment but not Ngfork.

Thanking  `@DEVIN RADER` using his blog [Configure Windows for Local Webhook Testing Using ngrok](https://www.twilio.com/blog/configure-windows-for-local-webhook-testing-using-ngrok-html)  for better understanding and as you are using ngrok extension for webhooks, if needed run IIS express which allows `http.sys` to accept requests from other external sources. To run this, we need to start visual studio as an administrator.

> Explicitly tell Windows to allow incoming requests to my ngrok domain by modifying the URL Access Control List (ACL).

When I click on overview logic app from vs code, I am able to get the expected output after checking the above reasons properly:

Right click on logicapp`->`  click on overview:

[image]

Overview of the logic app in VS code:

[image]

My workflow sample is also attached:
Right click on logic app  `->`  open in Designer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at screenshot I can tell the debugging is not started. Add the host configurations in task.json file (.vscode/task.json) and start the debugging (Run -> start debugging).. then you will be able to see workflow url in overview without any errors...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).